# How do I call a jQuery script after a delay?

Tags: jquery

I'm having a bit of trouble doing this - I understand that we can delay running a function using the delay() function in jQuery, but what about if you want to delay calling a external jQuery script? I've found discussions pertaining to the previous problem, but not the latter. Excuse me if the questions seems overly simple - I've a complete newbie to jQuery.

Here's the piece of relevant code in my HTML page:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("div.logo").fadeIn(3000);
        $("div.logo").delay(1000).fadeOut(1500); // slideUp("slow")
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('div.slider_class').queue();
    });
</script>
```

A quick description of what I'm trying to do is as follows:

1. A box fades in, delays a while, and fades out.
2. An [s3slider gallery](http://www.serie3.info/s3slider/) fades in, and features a slideshow of pictures.

I'd appreciate any pointers and suggestions...thanks!
Baggio.

Comment: Does [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) work for you?

Comment: Please don't include the entire script of a plugin in your question. Link to it if it's relevant.

Comment: What do you mean by "calling an external script"?  Do you mean calling a function in an external script?  If so, you either use the completion function of an existing jQuery animation or you use `setTimeout()` to schedule the calling of a function at a particular time from now in the future.

Comment: I'm sorry about my technical incompetence and lack of clarity in explaining my code. I originally found a script that'll allow me to display a gallery. As linked to above, it clearly says to simply call the function wrapped in <script> tags, which I understand, but I'd like to have the gallery fade in AFTER the box with the class "logo" fades out. I think I was trying too much to find a shortcut without even reading the script, so instead, I'll hand code a gallery instead. If you have any idea how to achieve this with the script linked above, however, I'm all ears. :D Will update later. Thx!

Comment: cool stuff...done! Imitating the effects of a photo gallery is easily doable with a few lines of well timed fadeIn and fadeOut - not as elegant a solution as the script I've seen, but works, thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 1):

```
$("div.logo").fadeIn(3000).delay(1000).fadeOut(1500, function(){
  // do your gallery fade here
});
```

That'll fade it in over 3 secs, wait another second, then fade it out over 1.5 seconds and then call whatever you put in the callback in `fadeOut`

Comment: Thanks, that's what I've already done, but that's not quite what I'm looking for - after fading in and out a box, I want to fade in a gallery. But thanks for the heads up anyway. :)

Comment: I've amended my answer above to give some extra info. If you want to do something after the fadeOut finishes, then pass the `fadeOut` function another function as the second parameter and do whatever you need to inside that function.